# How to find the element in Selenium after scroll?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wrote an Automation Code which redirects me up to here.
[image]

There are about 70 row in this popup, and the scroll bar is at the last row of the pop up and what I need is to click the setting value of the third row.
The X-path of 3rd row of the respective element is `//*[@class = 'slick-cell l3 r3 row_3 cid_U_Value']/child::div[1]`

Selenium couldn't find the element of the third row, but when I manually scroll the bar until 
the 3rd row is visible the element is found by selenium and performs accordingly. How can I solve this issue without manually scrolling.

```
//the element of the third row

[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//*[@class = 'slick-cell l3 r3 row_3 cid_U_Value']/child::div[1]")] 
public IWebElement serializeStage { get; set; }


((IJavaScriptExecutor)StaticDriver.driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", serializeStage);

serializeStage.Click();
```

but this also didn't help

Comment: Is the application lazy-loading the rows? There could be javascript setting the classes at runtime.

Comment: No the rows are not lazy-loading. I tried every thing IJavaScriptExecuter but the bar is not scrolled at the top. If I manually scroll the bar to the top, the script finds the element.

Comment: What error are you getting?can you share html of the page?

Comment: I found the Solution by taking the element of Name column of 70th row and sending keys as page Up,, Example :- driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class = 'slick-cell l2 r2 row_70 cid_Name active editable']/child::input")).SendKeys(Keys.PageUp)